# Code-first: Mapping entities to existing database tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 code-first with an existing database, but having problems mapping my entities to the database tables.

Normally, I would use database-first approach and have my entity and context code generated, but using the designer has become a huge pain.

I have set Database.SetInitializer(null) as I do not want EF to change my schema.

**Database schema:**

[image]

**Code-first:**

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseControlContext : DbContext
{
    public ReleaseControlContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReleaseControl"].ConnectionString) 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ReleaseControlContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

**Calling code:**

```
using(var context = new ReleaseControlContext())
{
    var projects = context.Projects.ToList();
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

> **SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Projects'.**

This is because my database table is *Project* and not *Projects*.  I don't want to rename my context's `DbSet<Project>` to "Project" because that would be semantically incorrect.

**Question:**

Do I have to use the fluent API/data annotations to map between the *Project* database table and the `DbSet<Project> Projects` collection?

Comment: I'm wonderung why it does not work; The table must be called Projects soemthing going wrong but as you said you can use Data annotation to force the name [Table("Projects")].

Comment: try to call the initializer before you create the DBContext; put it somewhere outside.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the

```
[Table("Project")] 
public class Project {
....
}
```

annotation against the Project entity, or in the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` you can call `modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");`.

Both would do the same thing.

Comment: Would any of these recognise my table keys, constraints and relationships or do I have to explicitly state this?

Comment: I don't know.  I would have thought the keys *should* be ok, by the fact you are using the convention of Entity+Id, but remapping the tables *may* cause issues (sorry IDK).  You do have the KeyAttribute annotation for your keys and there is the capability to map these, and your relationships in model builder.

Answer (score 9):

You should define a class (ie:`ProjectMap`) that inherits from the generic class `EntityTypeConfiguration(T)` where `T` is here your `Project` class.
In this `ProjectMap` class, you can define explicitly a table mapping :

```
this.ToTable("Project", "dbo");
```

The class `ProjectMap` should be called in the following method of your `DbContext` class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectMap());
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning `EntityTypeConfiguration`, keeps the mappings clean and separated for each Model.