# Entity Framework 6.1.1 can't get new Entity to work with Unity of Work Factory and Repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework

I added a new Entity to my MVC 5 Web API Project, but I can't get it to work with my existing SQL Database. My existing code uses the Unit of Work Factory and Repository pattern to read and write from the database, so I know the code works. There is no edmx file, so I believe the code was originally written using code first. Here are the steps I've taken so far.

Step 1) Added the new Entity to my Entities folder
Step 2) Updated DbContext file
Step 3) Updated UnitOfWork.cs file
Step 4) Manually created new SQL table using script
Step 5) Added the following code to my Web API Service

```
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
            {

//Code to create newentity object

uow.newEntityRepository.Insert(newentity);
await uow.SaveChangesAsync(); 
}
```

I'm not getting an error. The insert simply doesn't add the record to the database.

I've since created an Entity table map using the EntityTypeConfiguration and I'm calling it using the OnModelCreating Override.

**EntityTypeConfiguration**

```
public class NewEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<NewEntity>
    {
        public NewEntityMap() : base()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);


            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("NewEntity", "dbo");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            this.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnName("Created");
            this.Property(t => t.OfferId).HasColumnName("OfferId");
            this.Property(t => t.MerchantId).HasColumnName("MerchantId");
            this.Property(t => t.ConsumerId).HasColumnName("ConsumerId");
            this.Property(t => t.SMSMessage).HasColumnName("SMSMessage");
            this.Property(t => t.SendSMS).HasColumnName("SendSMS");
            this.Property(t => t.EmailMessage).HasColumnName("EmailMessage");
            this.Property(t => t.SendEmail).HasColumnName("SendEmail");
            this.Property(t => t.Source).HasColumnName("Source");
            this.Property(t => t.FromSMSNumber).HasColumnName("FromSMSNumber");
        }
    }
```

**OnModelCreating**

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new newEntityMap());
```

I still can't get the record to update in the table.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like based on this Stack Overflow question that Entities can be mapped manually without having to do a database migration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243796/code-first-mapping-entities-to-existing-database-tables

Comment: This blog post doesn't even mention the need for database migrations. http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF code-first is pretty darn simple so this should work. If you're not using migrations, you essentially just add a new model class (matching your existing table definition) and add the DbSet NewEntities to your DbContext class which it sounds like you did.

Couple of things to try to track down the issue by process of elimination.

1. Create a new empty Console App project for testing.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    /* Here's where we're gonna start troubleshooting */
}
```

2. Reference your entity project and try instantiating the Entity class first with all the necessary/required properties.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    // Test instantiating the Entity
    var newEntity = new NewEntity() { propName: value };
}
```

3. Run the project and make sure that works. If not, there's a problem with your entity. Otherwise, proceed to step 4.
4. Building on the code in step 2, add a reference to your project that contains your DbContext. Now try using the DbContext directly like so:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    // Test instantiating the Entity
    var newEntity = new NewEntity() { propName: value };

    // Now, let's test the Entity with the DbContext directly
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        db.NewEntities.Add(newEntity);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

5. Run/Debug the code above. If that fails, you should get an exception back from EF. Otherwise, proceed to step 6.
6. Building on the code in step 4. Add a reference to your project that contains your Repository. Now, try using the Repository directly like so:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    // Test instantiating the Entity
    var newEntity = new NewEntity() { propName: value };

    // Now, let's test the Entity with the DbContext directly
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        //db.NewEntities.Add(newEntity);
        //await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Now, let's test the entity with the DbContext and the Repository
        // Adjust the lines below as needed if you're not using a generic repository and/or if your insert method is called something else
        var repository = new EntityRepository<NewEntity>(db);
        repository.Insert(newEntity);
        // Comment out the line below if your repository internally calls SaveChangesAsync() on the DbContext
        // If your Repository class doesn't have a SaveChangesAsync method, you'll need to add one to test it
        await repository.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

7. If that fails, you should get an exception that you can track down. Otherwise, proceed to step 8.
8. Building on the code in step 6, add a reference to your project that contains your Unit of Work Factory (if it's not already referenced). Now, try using the Unit of Work factory directly like so:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    // Test instantiating the Entity
    var newEntity = new NewEntity() { propName: value };

    // Now, let's test the Entity with the DbContext directly
    //using (var db = new DbContext())
    //{
        //db.NewEntities.Add(newEntity);
        //await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Now, let's test the entity with the DbContext and the Repository
        // Adjust the lines below as needed if you're not using a generic repository and/or if your insert method is called something else
        //var repository = new EntityRepository<NewEntity>(db);
        repository.Insert(newEntity);
        // Comment out the line below if your repository internally calls SaveChangesAsync() on the DbContext
        //await repository.SaveChangesAsync();
    //}

    // Now, let's test the entity with the UnitOfWork
    var uow = new UnitOfWork();
    uow.NewEntityRepository.Insert(newEntity);
    await uow.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

9. If that fails, you should get an exception that you can track down. Otherwise, proceed to step 10.
10. If the above all worked without Dependency Injection, then I say there is something up with your component registration with your DI container. You'll need to make sure you have a real instance (implementation) of those interfaces bound and registered for runtime.

On the EF side, make sure you don't have any foreign keys or virtual navigation properties to other entities that aren't properly decorated or that you aren't properly populated. Also, make sure you are passing all the required properties for your given model. Without running it through a test project, your app could be swallowing an error that is occurring somewhere and you're just not seeing it, but with the process of elimination I outlined above, you should be able to track down the problem.

Once you track down the problem, you might want to reconsider using the Unit of Work and Repository patterns on top of Entity Framework since they essentially combine both of those patterns. See [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/220126#220126).

Good luck.

Comment: This is working now. Thanks for your help. I didn't have to issue any migration commands using Package Manager Console. I didn't have to use any tools to reverse engineer the table into an Entity / Model. All I really had to do was make sure that my Entity was setup correctly. Add the DbSet entry to the DBContex file and make sure my object was passing the correct values into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use nuget package manager console to generate the script to update the database?

Do you:

a) Have a 'Migrations' folder in your project?
b) Have a 'MigrationHistory' table in your database?
c) Is there a 'Database.SetInitializer' line anywhere in your code?

These would be indicators that you're running code first. The code from the DbContext might be useful.

Comment: I did not use the package manager console to generate the script to update the database. I wasn't sure that I needed to do that seeing as I manually created the new table using a database script.

Comment: I do have a Migrations folder in my main Web Project. It contains a Configuration.cs file. I have a dbo.MigrationsHistory table in my database, but there are no records in it. I also added this line to my DbContext file.  public DbSet<NewEntity> NewEntities { get; set; }

Comment: I found this line of code. `public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

You sure the conn string is pointing to the database you are expecting?

You added a DbSet for NewEntity to the DbContext?

What does the repository.Insert method do?

Are the uow and the repository using the same instance of the DbContext from the factory? Or are those both getting different instances of the context?  (i.e. the IoC is setup to not give the same instance on the same session or however you are setup.)

Comment: Yes, the connection string is correct. I'm using the same code with the other services in my Projects. Yes, I did add the DbSet for the NewEntity. Yes, the uow and repository is using the same instance of the DbContext. The uow and  repository uses all the same code, so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue. I'm thinking that I might have to use the Package Manager Console to have Entity Framework create the database and update the schema, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What happens if you call SaveChanges directly in the Insert method on the repo?  Does it still do nothing?

Is there any .Commit() you have to call?

Comment: There's no error and the app processes like everything worked. The .Insert calls this method. `public void Insert(T item)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(item);
        }` SaveChangesAsync() calls this method  `public Task SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }`

Comment: Do you have a TransactionScope above all this code that doesn't have .Commit() called on it?

Comment: Otherwise, I would Run SQL Profiler to see if your SQL statements are even going across the wire at all.